# Java, Weka: How can I find out what learners are compatible with what data types

Tags: java, weka

I am working on a few examples using Weka in Java.  I have created some exceptions by trying different datasets with different learners:

```
Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: 
weka.classifiers.functions.GaussianProcesses: Cannot handle date attributes!

Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException:
weka.classifiers.trees.j48.C45PruneableClassifierTree: Cannot handle numeric class!

Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: 
weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression: Cannot handle binary class!
```

Where can I find a table or a description of what datatypes can be fed to which learners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a bit of a look around for such a table and was unable to find one.  The reference to [UnsupportedAttributeTypeException](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/UnsupportedAttributeTypeException.html) doesn't really speak much for your question, and each of the model descriptions do not indicate the supported data types either.

Those who have a good knowledge of the models would have a fair idea of what should and shouldn't work, but if you are unsure about the mechanics of these models and want to give them a go, the above messages can likely appear.

Some data types can be converted to others to allow support for these models, such as NominalToBinary, but sometimes the models simply will not fit the data you would like to use.

It would be nice as a reference to see the supported data types for the model, though the errors outlined above provide a meaningful (though perhaps not so elegant) response that the data is unsupported for the model.

Sorry I couldn't help further.

Comment: Thanks for having a look Matthew.  You just got me thinking about how to automatically generate such a table.  Probably could orchestrate some exception handling and a enumeration of say 31 arff files with the various subsets of data as examples.  I think maybe one would just need to group the tests by interfaces, for example, it appears that Classifiers follow the general `buildClassifier` and `distribution for instance` type workflow.  I have yet to look into clustering methods.  Also I am still working on getting a big picture of what is supported.  Eg, regression trees etc.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have the Weka Source Code, you could also potentially look for references to UnsupportedAttributeTypeException.  This may eliminate some of the guesswork as well.

Comment: Excellent point, search for `Capability.NOMINAL_ATTRIBUTES` to see how it happens.